# Prove or disprove that $8c+1$ is square number.

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers, with $a-b$ prime, and $$3c^2=c(a+b)+ab.$$  Prove or disprove that $8c+1$ is square number.

Comment: When $c=7$ there is no $a$ and $b$ satisfying the listed requirements.

Comment: That being said, @Australia do you have any reason to believe this is true?

Comment: when $c=7$,then $(a+7)(b+7)=196=2^2\cdot 7^2$,no $a,b$ such conidition

Comment: Can you give an example to support the conjuncture?

Comment: An example to support is $a=6$, $b=1$, $c=3$

Comment: @Australia , same thing, switch $a$ and $b$ if you like.

Comment: oh,I  forget this example.

Comment: Another solution: $a=10, b=3, c=6$.

Comment: I've tested every combination with $1 \leq a,b,c \leq 100$ and the conjecture is true so far. The working triples so far are $(6,1,3), (10,3,6), (21,10,15),(28,15,21),(45,28,36),(55,36,45),(78,55,66).$

Comment: @A.P.,Thank you give this lots of  example support the conjecture

Comment: why  have two closed this problem?

Comment: Australia, where did you get this??????????????????????

Comment: @Australia I have edited your post slightly to make it more readable.

Comment: Perhaps better way to state the equation is $(a+c)(b+c)=4c^2$

Comment: @WillJagy,a  frend give it.maybe first is he conjecture

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's true! Here we go: Write $b=a-p$. Then, if you write the expression as a quadratic equation in $c$, you get $3c^2-(2a-p)c+ap-a^2=0.$ Now, by the quadratic formula, see that since we want $c$ to be integer, we must have $(2a-p)^2-12(ap-a^2)=x^2$ for some, say positive, integer $x$. Rewriting in a better way, you get $(4a-2p)^2=x^2+3p^2$, which turns to be $(4a-2p-x)(4a-2p+x)=3p^2.$ Now, since $p$ is prime, there are a few different cases we should look at:

1) $4a-2p-x=1, 4a-2p+x=3p^2$: Isolating $2a-p$ and $x$, you get $x=\frac{3p^2-1}{2}, 2a-p=\frac{3p^2+1}{4}.$ Plugging in these two in quadratic formula, you get $c=\frac{9p^2-1}{24}$ or $c=\frac{-3p^2+3}{24}$, where first one cannot be an integer since numerator is not divisible by $3$, and the latter is not positive. So, there is no solution from this case.

2) $4a-2p-x=3, 4a-2p+x=p^2$. Similarly, you get $2a-p=\frac{p^2+3}{4}, x=\frac{p^2-3}{2}$. Plug in these, and eliminate the possible negative root, you'll get $c=\frac{p^2-1}{8}$, which tells that $8c+1=p^2.$

3) $4a-2p-x=p, 4a-2p+x=3p$. From here, you get $x=p, 2a-p=\frac{p}{2}$, which forces $p$ to be $2$, so you get $a=\frac{3}{2}$, hence no solution from this case too.

Note that these are all possible cases, since $4a-2p-x<4a-2p+x.$

Comment: I edited, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, with $a−b\in\mathbb{P}$, and 
$$4c^2=(a+c)(b+c).$$ Then $$a=r^2t-c \,\,\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\,\,b=s^2t-c\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\,\ 2c=rst$$ for some $r, s, t:=\gcd(a+c,b+c) \in\mathbb{Z}^+.$ Since $$a-b=t(r-s)(r+s)$$ is prime, we must have $r=s+1$ and $t=1$. Hence $$2c=s(s+1)\implies \color{Blue}{8c+1=(2s+1)^2.}$$

Comment: Why are $c+a$, $c+b$ squares?

Comment: Excuse me... I can see that we have $c+a = r^2 t$, $c+b = s^2 t'$, but why are $t = t'$?

Comment: Product of $(a+c)$ and $(b+c)$ should be a perfect square. Suppose $\gcd(a+c, b+c)=t$ for some $t.$ It may or may not be a square. Then we have above result.

Comment: Community is wrong there; the case Nilan gave is the only possible case. $t\ge 1, r+s\ge 2$, so we must have $r-s>0$ and $t=1, r-s=1$. This is the best solution in this thread. In case of misunderstanding, $\Bbb N$ here denotes positive integers.

Comment: I've edited the solution to make some things more clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, but it might push someone else in the right direction. The following primitive Maple code searches for solutions within the bounds $1 \leq a,b,c \leq m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}.$ (And under the additional constraint $b > a$ since the problem is symmetrical in $a$ and $b.$) For silly programming reasons my assumption is that $b - a$ is prime, so switch the $a$'s and $b$'s from the comments around.

```
m := 200;
for a to m do
for b from a+1 to m do
for c to m do
if `and`(evalb(sqrt((c*(a+b)+a*b)*(1/3)) = c), isprime(b-a)) then print([a, b, c], b-a, sqrt(8*c+1)) end if
end do end do end do;
```

The output for $m = 200$ is the following:

```
[1, 6, 3], 5, 5
[3, 10, 6], 7, 7
[10, 21, 15], 11, 11
[15, 28, 21], 13, 13
[28, 45, 36], 17, 17
[36, 55, 45], 19, 19
[55, 78, 66], 23, 23
[91, 120, 105], 29, 29
[105, 136, 120], 31, 31
[153, 190, 171], 37, 37
```

The noteworthy thing here is that **it is always the case that $8c+1 = (b-a)^2.$** Hence presumably to show that $8c+1$ is a square number one should try to show that it's exactly the square of the prime $b-a.$

Comment: @John No; for instance the triple $(2,35,14)$ satisfies OP's equation but $8c + 1 = 113 \neq 1089 = (b-a)^2.$

Comment: $35-2=33$ is not prime though.

Comment: @vgmath Indeed; John asked whether $8c+1=(b−a)^2$ is also true when $b-a$ isn't prime, so I showed him a counterexample.

Comment: @vgmath : I was asking about if the result is still true when $b-a$ is not prime.

Comment: @A.P. Sorry about that, I misunderstood then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make it easier.  Parameterization - that is, the solution of Diophantine equations.

$$3c^2=c(a+b)+ab$$

Have this form.

$$c=(p+s)s$$

$$a=(3s-p)s$$

$$b=(p+s)p$$

Then the difference will be equal.

$$a-b=3s^2-ps-p^2-ps=3s^2-2ps-p^2=4s^2-(p+s)^2=$$

$$=(2s-p-s)(2s+p+s)=(s-p)(3s+p)$$

This number will be easiest if  $s=p+1$

Substitute and find the number itself.

$$8c+1==8s(p+s)+1=8(p+1)(2p+1)+1=$$

$$=8(2p^2+3p+1)+1=16p^2+24p+9=(4p+3)^2$$

All. It is a square.